# Incredibly bad edit including editors questions to op, approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Why was this edit approved?  https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52778

Comment: Edit was improved rather then approved.

Answer (score 5):

The edit actively improved extremely poor grammar. This is good and wanted and it is something we should be encouraging. It takes a lot of time and effort to copy edit a post like that so destroying that work is detrimental and should be avoided.

Unfortunately, it also included some edits that should have been placed as comments and the user who approved this edit should have removed them.

Please note, however that rolling the question back to the pre-edited version was about the worst thing you could do.

If there are issues with the editor doing things like adding in questions, **edit them out**. We should avoid going the lazier way and rolling back, though.

Plus, as wrong as the questions by the editor were, they actually got answered by the OP, so rolling back the question to the first version removed information that was added by the OP, so the roll back did just as much, if not more harm to the question.

I have edited the question by rolling it back to the most recent version and properly integrating the added information.

Comment: No, it's don't be lazy and do more harm by rolling back an actually helpful edit instead of improving the edit. The rollback button is significantly easier to push than to actually fix the edit.

Comment: It takes significantly more time and effort to fix the crappy grammar than to remove the editor comments.

Answer (score 3):

Because it improved the quality of question without changing the meaning. And it was later improved as well.

I removed some part of it to improve a bit more. Any edit that clarifies the question or improve the quality of a question is a good edit.

There are many questions I have seen across the site which received more attention after some improvements.

Anyway, I kept editor's question so OP can reply to them by editing the post, that will eventually improve the post. And it did.

Comment: Edits are ***not the appropriate location for comments by an editor. It actually harmed the question! !!***